# Blender Scripting - Import Collada file and save it as .blend

Tags: python, blender

Right now, I have a script in python that converts a collada (.dae) file into a blender file (.blend).

In the command Line:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender.exe --background --python c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop\convert_collada_to_blend.py -- c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop
\Maya.dae -- c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop\Result.blend
```

My script:

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

dae_in = argv[0]
blend_out = argv[1]

bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=dae_in)
bpy.ops.render.render()
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=blend_out)
```

After executing the command, I get a lot of output indicating that It's actually doing something. However, at the end of the process, I don't know where the result file is being saved.

Any Help From you guys, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a file named `--` in the current directory when you enter the command, in the temp directory, or possibly the same dir as blender.exe.

The location of the [temp directory](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir) may vary, try

```
import tempfile
print(tempfile.gettempdir())
```

You use `argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]` to get the args after the first '--' which includes the extra '--' between the two paths that you are expecting to be used. The second of these is what you are assigning to `blend_out`

I expect the command you want to use is

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe --background
--python c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop\convert_collada_to_blend.py
-- c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop\Maya.dae c:\Users\c.diaz\Desktop\Result.blend
```

Also of note is your use of `bpy.ops.render.render()`, this doesn't save the rendered image (assuming you have a camera setup). Use `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` to have the rendered image saved to disk. You may also want to set `bpy.context.scene.render.filepath` to specify where the image is saved.

Comment: It works!  My new question is... Do i need bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=blend_out) in order to save the file? or the file is saved after executing  bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=dae_in)

Comment: Yes you need to specifically save the blend file if you want to keep it.